# Vite + ReactJS + Rollup - Create library that can be used in another project/index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, rollupjs

I'm trying to create a JS library that others can import like so in a `index.html` file

```
<script type="module" src="/dist/my-client-lib.js"></script>
<script>
  // here I want to use functions and components from 'my-client-lib.js', e.g. 'add'
  console.log(add(1,2)
</script>
```

`add` is a function I defined in the vite project under `src/lib/add.ts` and exported in the `src/lib/index.ts` like so

`export { default as add } from './add';`

My vite config file looks like

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
        lib: {
            // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib/index.ts'),
            name: 'MyClientLib',
            // the proper extensions will be added
            fileName: 'my-client-lib',
            formats: ['es', 'cjs', 'umd', 'iife'],
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
            // into your library
            external: ['react'],
            output: {
                // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
                // for externalized deps
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

And I create it with `npm run build` which creates the `my-client-lib.js` file that I'm trying to import in the `index.html` file shown above.

But I'm still getting

```
(index):25 Uncaught TypeError: add is not a function
    at (index):25:32
```

How can I use the functions imported by the lib? As an extension, if the lib exports actual React components like let's say a Button, how can I "mount" it in the index.html?